# How display text in password field

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, passwords

I have the password field on page. I want to display text "Enter password" on screen before entering password but on focus when user enter password it should go back to password type

EDIT: I am using Jquery as well so any small jquery solution will do

Comment: Is jQuery an option, or just vanilla javascript?

Comment: @Nick I would not think so because it is not one of his tags.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

***[Latest revisision to include IE support]***
*<sup>Update for IE9: Version 9 of IE allows the change of the type attribute for input elements of type text/password back and forth</sup>*

As mentioned in the comments (and verified) the previous examples did not work in IE as it does not allow the change of the type by script ... Here is a workaround, which replaces the element with another back-and-forth (*code assumes you start with a text box*)

```
var element = document.getElementById('mysearch');

var text_to_show = 'Enter Password';

element.value = text_to_show; // set the message for the first time

element.onfocus = function(){ 
                       if (this.value == text_to_show) 
                           {
                             var newElement = convertType(this);
                            newElement.value = '';
                            setTimeout(function(){document.getElementById(newElement.id).focus()},100);
                           }
                       }
element.onblur = function(){ 
                       if (this.value == '') 
                          {
                            var newElement = convertType(this);
                            newElement.value = text_to_show;
                          }
                    }


function convertType(elem)
{
    var input = document.createElement('input');
    input.id = elem.id;
    input.value = elem.value;
    input.onfocus = elem.onfocus;
    input.onblur = elem.onblur;
    input.className = elem.className;
    if (elem.type == 'text' )
      { input.type = 'password'; }
    else
      { input.type = 'text'; }

    elem.parentNode.replaceChild(input, elem);         
  return input;
}
```

***[update]***

scrap the original answer, i missed the part that you want to keep the field as password (*with hidden contents*)

**Revised answer**:

```
var element = document.getElementById('mysearch');

var text_to_show = 'Enter Password';
element.type="text"; // set the type to text for the first time
element.value = text_to_show; // set the message for the first time
element.onfocus = function(){ 
                       if (this.value == text_to_show) 
                           {
                            this.type="password";
                            this.value = '';
                           }
                       }
element.onblur = function(){ 
                       if (this.value == '') 
                          {
                            this.type="text";
                            this.value = text_to_show;
                          }
                       }
```

***[original answer]***

```
var element = document.getElementById('inputID'); 
//  inputID should be the ID given to the password element

var text_to_show = 'Enter Password'
element.value = text_to_show;
element.onfocus = function(){ if (this.value == text_to_show) this.value = '';}
element.onblur = function(){ if (this.value == '') this.value = text_to_show;}
```

Comment: That wouldn't work on a password field, as `Enter Password` will appear as `***********`.

Comment: @voyager, yes i missed that part in the question ..
revised answer to correct this

Comment: @Gaby, just one thing: have you tested if this works on IE6-8, Opera and Chrome? My gut feeling is that IE6 *might* be a problem.

Comment: Good point @voyager, i have not tried it at IE6.. will do so later at home and post the results and if needed workarounds..

Comment: IE (all versions, as far as I know) doesn't allow you to change the type between text and password.

Comment: @Matthew & @voyager, Added cross-browser version (it replaces the element..)..
tested with IE6, FF, Safari, Opera, Chrome..

Comment: But guys- what about the Browsers password manager & firefox caching?
After page load the browser inject content, if from the manager or the cache, than what? How to get those events? .select() / .change() / or any other event i tried to attach to the element, just didn't manage to catch.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [this jQuery plugin](http://fuelyourcoding.com/scripts/infield/), which supports password fields.

Answer (score 3):

You can either give it an image background with the text `Enter Password` that you change dynamically using javascript (ideally by just removing a CSS class),

```
<input type="password" class="enter-password"> or
<input type="password" style="background-image:url('enter-password.png');">
```

or place a fake `input` that you replace with javascript for a password `input`.

I'm not sure how well it would cross browser to change the type of `input` on the fly.

`document.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].type = "text" /* change a hidden field to text*/` works on Firefox, but I wouldn't rely on it working well on IE without testing.

Comment: But your are using bytes for an image for nothing when you can do it pure Javascript. Also you do not want a password field to become text if you entered something into it revealing your password.

Comment: @Jon: See Gaby's answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2430109/how-display-text-in-password-field/2430161#2430161 That's what I'm proposing. The only reason I also proposed the image based solution is out of concern of good behavior of the various browsers out there.

Comment: This is the easiest and least-intrusive solution.  Bravo.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to use a plugin (like the one in [SLaks' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2430109/how-display-text-in-password-field/2430128#2430128)), you have to either position a label above the password field (what the plugin does), or hide the password field and show a text input in its place until it gets the focus.

Internet Explorer doesn't let you change an input's type from "password" to "text", so any solution that tries to do that won't work in IE.

Here's an example that works in at least IE7 (it *should* work in IE6, but I haven't tried it), Chrome, and Firefox.

```
jQuery(function($) {
    function make_label_field(password_input, label) {
        var new_input = document.createElement("input");
        new_input.type = "text";
        new_input.size = password_input.size;
        new_input.className = password_input.className;
        new_input.setAttribute("style", password_input.getAttribute("style"));
        // Copy any additional properties you need. You may want to add a class
        // to style the label differently

        new_input.value = label;

        $(new_input).focus(function() {
            $(this).hide();
            $(password_input).show().focus();
        });
        return new_input;
    }

    $("input[type=password]").each(function() {
        $(this).after(make_label_field(this, "Enter password")).hide();
    }).blur(function() {
        if (this.value == "") {
            $(this).hide().next().show();
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**[ revised answer ]** Added compatibility for ie6 from [this website](http://bytes.com/topic/javascript/answers/705445-dynamically-change-input-type-text-password)

```
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="">
  <input onfocus="clear_field(this,'Enter Username')" onBlur="revert_field(this,'Enter Username')" name="username" type="text" id="username" value="Enter Username" />
  <p>
<input type="text" id="passwordtext" value="Password" onclick="switchto(1)" onkeydown="switchto(1)">
<input type="password" id="password" value="" onblur="if (this.value=='')switchto(0)" style="display:none">
  <p>
    <input  type="submit" name="button" id="button" value="Submit" />
  </p>
</form>

<script>
function switchto(q){
    if (q){
        document.getElementById('passwordtext').style.display="none";
        document.getElementById('password').style.display="inline";
        document.getElementById('password').focus();
    } else {
        document.getElementById('password').style.display="none";
        document.getElementById('passwordtext').style.display="inline";
    }
}
function clear_field(field,text){
if(field.value==text){
    field.value = "";
    }
}
function revert_field(field,text){
if(field.value==""){
    field.value = text;
    }
}
</script>
```

**[previous post ]**
maybe this help.

```
<script>
function clear_field(field){
field.value='';
}
function change(){
document.getElementById('pass').value='';
document.getElementById('pass').type='password';

}
</script>
```

Comment: How would you change it back to text if nothing was entered?

Comment: pls check. added revert function :)

Comment: if you do not want text_to_show variable, you can also set text variable like clear_text function.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to do it but here is one way.
I'm not saying that this is efficient but this will explain better of what is happening.

Copy and paste this to try it out!

```
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">

    text=document.createElement("input");
    text.type="text";
    text.value="password";
    text.setAttribute("onclick", 'toPassword();');
    text.setAttribute("onblur", 'toText();');
    document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].appendChild(text);

    function toText()
    {
        if(document.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].value=="password" || document.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].value=="")
        {
            document.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].type="text"; 
            document.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].value="password"
        }
    }

    function toPassword()
    {
        if(document.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].value=="password" || document.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].value=="")
        {
            document.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].type="password";
            document.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].value=""
        }
    }
</script>
</body>
```

It creates a text field with value of `password` and then when you click in it, it then changes to password field and removes its value. If you click and you did not enter anything then it will return to a `text` and change its value to `password`.

You may also enter a text field along with less javascript code too, all you would need is the functions.

If you want this to work in IE you would need to create two inputs, one for text and one for password and alternate `display=none` and `display=block` on each of them.

```
element.style.display="none";
```