# how to change textbox textmode using jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net

i have a login component and within it the password field has a textmode of singlline

what i am trying to do is on focus the textmode will change to password

i tried this :

```
$(function () {
   $(".PassTextBox").focus(function (pas) {
       $(".PassTextBox").attr("TextMode", "Password");
   });
});
```

but it didn't work

using asp.net 3.5 , thanks

Comment: Interesting. Is there a reason why you want to do this on the client side, instead of simply using a `TextBox` control in password mode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to change the "type" attribute to password.  "TextMode" is an asp.net control attribute, but on the client side it gets turned into an HTML input, which has a type attribute:  http://htmlhelp.com/reference/html40/forms/input.html

```
$(function () {
$(".PassTextBox").focus(function (pas) {
    $(".PassTextBox").attr("Type", "Password");
});
});
```

**UPDATE:**
After testing this to confirm it works, it appears changing the type may not be supported on all browsers or by jQuery.  [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1544317/jquery-change-type-of-input-field) will give you some more insight.  My suggestion is to put two fields on the form and dynamically show/hide them to give the same effect.

Comment: it will not work in IE (*pre-IE9*) though .. you need to replace the field.

Comment: yes your right it would be more efficient to add two fields, thanks

Answer (score 3):

Why not display it as a password field from the start ?

If you have to, take a look at [How display text in password field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2430109/how-display-text-in-password-field/2430161#2430161)

It is not as simple as it seems because IE (*before v9*) does not allow to dynamically change the type of the textbox, so you will have to actually replace it with another one.

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

```
$(function () {
  $(".PassTextBox").focus(function (pas) {
    $(".PassTextBox").attr("type", "password");
  });
});
```

Hope this works.